# e.printStackTrace is the same like to print java method call stack?

Tags: java

Hi I have a try catch block, in this i need to print the call stack, when I have an IOException. I thought, that is only e.printStackTrace()  but I am not really sure, because of this, I want to ask here.

Comment: What is your question? `printStackTrace()` will print the stack trace of the exception

Comment: I need to print the call stack

Comment: Can you specify more? Is that you would like to know any methods other than `printStackTrace()`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify the question. I can only assume you want to know the difference between `printStackTrace()` and printing `getStackTrace()`. Starting from the result difference,

`printStackTrace()`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: [fileName] (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:639)
    at [className].main([className].java:11)
```

`getStackTrace()` with `println()`:

```
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:639)
[className].main([className].java:11)
```

And the documentation of `printStackTrace()` from [Class Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()) (and you can find more from it):

> Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream. This method prints a stack trace for this Throwable object on the error output stream that is the value of the field System.err.

More importantly:

> The first line of output contains the result of the toString() method for this object. Remaining lines represent data previously recorded by the method fillInStackTrace().

On the other hand, `getStackTrace()` is actually a partial replica of `printStackTrace()`:

> Provides programmatic access to the stack trace information printed by printStackTrace(). Returns an array of stack trace elements, each representing one stack frame.

Hope this answer help you well.